# importing data to SAS

Tags: sas

I am using SAS Enterprise Guide and I have a problem importing data(excel,csv) in to SAS, when ever I try to import data I get this error

"failed to transcode data from utf-16le to wlatin 1 encoding because it contained characters which are not supported by your SAS session encoding".

I tried a few different files and I always get the same error,when I tried importing the files to SAS on a different computer it worked so its not a problem with the specific files,does anybody have any idea what causes this error and what needs to be done?

Answer (score 1):

Check the setting for the ENCODING option on your SAS session. Compare it to the one on the machine that can read the file.

Note that you must set the ENCODING value when SAS starts. So for EG that means changing the settings on the SAS server that uses to run SAS code.

Comment: A small instruction how to work with UTF-16 files http://support.sas.com/kb/16/355.html